# Class Singleton or Component. It must be called from different places

Tags: java, spring-boot, singleton

I have a situation where I need to keep in memory some data using spring boot and this will be update it from time to time. I need to keep it in a map but I'm a little confused if I should implement my own Singleton and use component annotation.

I know that for annotation component by default the object will use Singleton but in this case I have to use from 3 different classess A, B and C. My question here is, will it create a RepositoryComponent for class A, another for B and another for C and each one will be singleton? Or it will create only one for A and then when B wants to create it will see that there is one already created and will use that one and the same for C.

Otherwise I feel that I need to have my own Singleton implementation

```
Class Repository {
    Map<String, Config> db = new hashMap<>;
    ... singleton implementation

    public String getConfig(string key) { 
    return db.get(key);
   }
}

@Component
Class RepositoryComponent {
    Map<String, Config> db = new hashMap<>;

    public String getConfig(string key) { 
       return db.get(key);
    }
}

@Component
Class A { 
    @Autowire
    RepositoryComponent c;

    public someMethod() {
       Repository.getInstance().getConfig("key");
       c.getConfig("key");
    }
}

@Component
Class B { 
   @Autowire
   RepositoryComponent c;

   public someMethod() { 
      Repository.getInstance().getConfig("key");
      c.getConfig("key");
   }
}

@Component
Class C { 
    @Autowire
    RepositoryComponent c;
    
    public someMethod() { 
       Repository.getInstance().getConfig("key");
       c.getConfig("key");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you annotated a class with @Component, within same ApplicationContext there will be only one bean of that type. That's the default behavior.

If you annotated a class with @Component and @Scope("prototype"), Spring will create a new instance every time when it is request.

Answer (score 0):

Only one `RepositoryComponent` bean will be created since you are using `@Component` which means that its scope is Singleton. As a consequence the one that will be injected in Class A, B and C is exactly the same (all requests for that bean name will return the same object, which is cached).
Additionally, any modifications to the `RepositoryComponent` bean will be reflected in all references to the bean.